# How to check the file handle leak for a Java program?

Tags: java

My java code seems have handle leak, which debug tool is suitable to check that?

Comment: Share you code so others can see what you are talking about.

Comment: Let me guess: "FileNotFoundException: too many open files" ?
It'd be nice if there was more ways to track open file handles *in the java debugger*.
"lsof" alone most times is not enough to really track down bugs like this.
+1'd

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559184/whats-a-good-pattern-for-a-java-unit-test-that-ensures-that-you-are-properly-cl/70601199#70601199

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lsof command will list all the files that are associated with the program.

Answer (score 4):

Since no example was given, I am adding mine

```
package org.gradle;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
public class FileDescriptorDemoOne {

    static int index_count;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              index_count++;
            // do stuff
              File file = new File("/tmp/helloworld.txt");
                FileDescriptor fd;
                FileOutputStream fos1;
                try {
                    fos1 = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    fd = fos1.getFD();
                    //passing FileDescriptor to another  FileOutputStream
                    FileOutputStream fos2 = new FileOutputStream(fd);
                    fos2.write(index_count++);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
          }
        }, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Clearly above code would leak file descriptor every few seconds.

To catch this use

> lsof | grep helloworld

```
java       6015 vic    8w     REG                1,4         12 86076888 /private/tmp/helloworld.txt
java       6015 vic    9w     REG                1,4         12 86076888 /private/tmp/helloworld.txt
java       6015 vic   10w     REG                1,4         12 86076888 /private/tmp/helloworld.txt
```

Also on can use [File Leak Detector](http://file-leak-detector.kohsuke.org/) or [FLD Jenkin Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/File+Leak+Detector+Plugin)